# Window execution create components zk version 9.0.1.2

Tags: java, zk

While opening the window getting this error in version 9.0.1.2. And it's working fine in 8.5.0 version. After upgrading the version from 8.5.0 to 9.0.1.2 this error occurred.

window = (Window) Executions.createComponents(url, parent, params);
window.doModal();

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "auto"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.zkoss.zul.Grid.isVflex(Grid.java:420)
        at org.zkoss.zkmax.zul.impl.LiveGridDataLoader.isCropper(LiveGridDataLoader.java:392)
        at org.zkoss.zul.Grid.renderProperties(Grid.java:1791)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redraw(AbstractComponent.java:2175)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redrawChildren(AbstractComponent.java:2266)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redraw(AbstractComponent.java:2207)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redrawChildren(AbstractComponent.java:2266)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redraw(AbstractComponent.java:2207)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redrawChildren(AbstractComponent.java:2266)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redraw(AbstractComponent.java:2207)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redrawChildren(AbstractComponent.java:2266)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.redraw(AbstractComponent.java:2207)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiVisualizer.redraw(UiVisualizer.java:1016)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiVisualizer.redrawComponents(UiVisualizer.java:1030)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiVisualizer.addResponsesForCreatedPerSiblings(UiVisualizer.java:882)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiVisualizer.getResponses(UiVisualizer.java:746)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.getResponses(UiEngineImpl.java:1575)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1345)
        at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:611)
        at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:487)
        at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:495)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to ask a question that can be answered / solved.

The error can be explained by the source code of the isVflex method on grid itself (however that information might not help your actual problem, whatever that might be)

v8.5.0: https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/v8.5.0/zul/src/org/zkoss/zul/Grid.java#L399-L408

v9.0.1.2:
https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/v9.0.1.2/zul/src/org/zkoss/zul/Grid.java#L412-L421

The value 'auto' is not handled by this method, leading to this error.

If you provide a correct value (null, '', 'true', 'min' or a number) the error will go away.

The same exception should have happened in both versions 8.5.0 and 9.0.1.2 given the value 'auto'.

Unfortunately you didn't provide a working/failing example to investigate so I can't comment on that.